# Angular JS service sending coordinates to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, maps

My app needs to get a path ( list of latitude and longitudes )in order to display it on a map.

I created a basic controller that does all the api calls.

```
function mainController($scope, $http){

  $http.get('/api/lastrun')
    .success(function(data){
      $scope.lastrun = data;
    })
    .error(function(data){
      console.log('Error: ' + data);
    });
}
```

lastrun has a path array that lets you access the each position.

I created a mapController using angular-leaf-directive

```
function mapController($scope, positionService){
  angular.extend($scope, {
              run: {
                  lat:  0.0,
                  lng:  0.0,
                  zoom: 4
              },
              path: {
                  p1: {
                      color: 'red',
                      weight: 2,
                      latlngs: [
                          { lat: 51.50, lng: -0.082 }, //here is an example of lat and lng in this controller
                          { lat: 48.83, lng: 2.37 },
                          { lat: 0, lng: 7.723812 }
                      ]
                  }
                }
          });
}
```

What I want to do seems pretty easy. I just want to put the array of positions I get while calling /api/lastrun into my mapController in latlngs.

I'm not completely familiar with Services in AngularJS, but I tried to built mine (positionService). However it didn't work.

Does anyone here know how I can proceed in order to create with my service an array containing a list of {lat : , lng: } and call it into my mapController ?

Answer (score 0):

I would have done :

```
$scope.lastrun = [];
$http.get('/api/lastrun')
    .success(function(data){
       angular.forEach(data, function (value) {
         $scope.lastrun.push({lat : value.lat, lng : value.lng});
       });
     }
    })
```

and then :

```
path: {
              p1: {
                  color: 'red',
                  weight: 2,
                  latlngs: $scope.lastrun
              }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I don't thing it's going to work as the http request and the array I shall fill are on two different controllers

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found a solution. I use Adrien's solution in my service, not in my controller and then return the lastrunpos array to my mapController. Here's my code :

```
var selftracking = angular.module('selftracking',["leaflet-directive"])

  selftracking.service('positionService', function($http){
    var lastrunpos = [];
    $http.get('/api/lastrun')
      .success(function(data){
        angular.forEach(data.path, function (value) {
         lastrunpos.push({lat : value.latitude, lng : value.longitude});
       });
     });
     return {
       getPos : function() {
          return lastrunpos;
       }
     }
  });

function mainController($scope, $http){
  //Get all the last activities in the front page
  $http.get('/api/lastactivity')
    .success(function(data){
      $scope.lastactivity = data;
    })
    .error(function(data){
      console.log('Error: '+ data);
    });
  $http.get('/api/lastrun')
    .success(function(data){
      $scope.lastrun = data;
    })
    .error(function(data){
      console.log('Error: ' + data);
    });
}

function mapController($scope, positionService){
  angular.extend($scope, {
              run: {
                  lat: 51.505,
                  lng: -0.09,
                  zoom: 4
              },
              path: {
                  p1: {
                      color: 'red',
                      weight: 8,
                      latlngs: positionService.getPos()
                  }
                }
          });
}
```